# Return a given value in a table excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if you could help me with this.

Currently I am making a calculator for [Vo2 Max](https://www.verywellfit.com/what-is-vo2-max-3120097) utilizing a pre existing table.
The formula I am trying to make would use a persons heart rate and work load to return the proper L/min.

Example

```
| Heart Rate | 300 kpm/min | 600kpm |
|------------|-------------|--------|
| 120        | 3.4         | 4.0    |
| 121        | 3.3         | 3.9    |
```

I am stuck, I am trying to use index match but I am kinda stuck as I can’t seem to get it to look for the proper header and then corresponding heart rate. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Hey I just noticed that when I published this the example got screwed. I’ll re upload later

Comment: Added a link for `Vo2 Max` as had to google what it was - what's `L/min` standing for and what is the math formula to calculate it?  With that info it will be easier to translate to an Excel formula.

Comment: Or is it a case of you enter the heart rate - e.g. _121_ and then a kpm value, e.g. _600_ and you want it to return _3.9_?

Comment: Yes sorry it has to do with entering heart rate and then a value to return 3.9. I have another formula to determine Vo2 ( Ventilation of Oxygen) in Litres per min.

Comment: Is the desired output always in column 3? If so you can use  `=vlookup(F2,A:A.C:C.3.FALSE)` Or are you trying to calculate 3.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table headings could do with updating to:

```
| Heart Rate | 300 | 600 |
|------------|-----|-----|
| 120        | 3.4 | 4.0 |
| 121        | 3.3 | 3.9 |
```

If you want to show `300 kpm/min` as a heading you can give the cell a custom number format of `# "kpm/min"`.  This way the cell will only contain the value `300`, but displays as `300 kpm/min`.

With the table in the range `A1:C3` you can use this formula to find the row number (relative to the table) the Heart Rate is on (change 121 to a cell reference):
`=MATCH(121,$A$1:$A$3,0)`
Returns the value *row* 3.

This formula will return the column number:
`=MATCH(600,$A$1:$C$1,0)`
Returns the value *column* 3.

This formula will return the value from row 3, column 3 on the supplied table range:
`=INDEX($A$1:$C$3,3,3)`

Or as a single formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$3,MATCH(121,$A$1:$A$3,0),MATCH(600,$A$1:$C$1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this tonight :)